# How do I add a query string parameter to my URL programmatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do. I have 2 tables in my application. One is Project and the other is Bug. One proyect can have several bugs.

[image]

I'm able to add/edit/delete projects. To each project in the database I added an ActionLink so if you click over its name, it should show all the bugs related to that project.

I tell "should show" because I'm able to see the new page with the ID on the URL which is fine, but I haven't been able to assign a specific Project ID to the BUG.

[image]

For example:

BUG has description, status, date...and Project ID (which i would like to use to filter my bugs)

So what I would like to do is to get the ID of the project which has been clicked, so when I hit create action, i can store the ProjectID in the BugDatabase with all other values that are stored automatically by MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the value with the action link?

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "BUG",                                                  
    "PROJECT",                                    
    "Project",                                                   
    new {                                                     
        ProjectId = myProjectId, 
    }
)
```

Comment: I can see the list of proyects. What I want is to create a new bug using the view created by MVC. The data for the bug (Description, date..) is entered by the user and stored in the database. (I didn't change the create action). But i need to store another value in the database related to the project clicked which is IDProject.

Comment: I'm thinking in your [httpget] controller action you need to have it accept PROJECTID as a variable. So when you go to create a new bug you can pass in the projectid that is appropriate to the project clicked on.